# Using assets on React Library Rollup

Tags: reactjs, assets, rollup

I'm using the HarveyD template:
https://github.com/HarveyD/react-component-library

And I need to use some assets in my components. But, when I import the library into my react project, the following error appears:

> ./node_modules/components-teste/build/index.esm.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../assets/add.svg' in '/home/gbelther/Projects/my-projects/app-teste/node_modules/components-teste/build'

Looking the "/build/index.esm.js", the imports into build folder are not correctly, because they are "../assets" (import on component library), and not "./assets" (build folder).

The structure folder is:

- src

  - component1
  - component2
  - assets
- rollup.config.js

Someone know if has any configuration to set to use assets or what I'm doing wrong?

A example project is:
https://github.com/gbelther/library-teste

Comment: did you found anything ?
I also stuck in the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found it, Thanks

It should be externally added in rollup.config.js

```html
external: [ 'react', '@elastic/datemath', '@elastic/eui' ]
```